# Is it exception-safe that return the right value which is return of function in c++?

Tags: c++, exception

Is it exception-safe that to return the right value which is return of function in c++?
For example,

```
template<typename Iterator, typename T>
T my_accumulate(Iterator first, Iterator last) {
    return std::accumulate(first, last, T());
};
```

At above code, `std::accumulate` can throw.
What happen if `std::accumulate` throws?
T() can make memory leak?
or is it safe for some reason?
How can I make exception safe code for this?

Comment: There is no leak in this code. `T()` creates a temp object in local automatic memory. The object is destroyed when it goes out of scope, regardless of whether an exception is thrown or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What happen if std::accumulate throws?

The temporary `T` is destroyed (just like if returned normally) and the exception is propagated to the caller.

> T() can make memory leak?

Not unless the class `T` itself is horribly broken.

> or is it safe for some reason?

The function is exception safe.